# How can I get the file path in androidTest?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing

I have a androiTest which is needed to test a file . And I put a pdf here :

[image]

And I use the code to get the file path :

1.

```
File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("aa.pdf").getFile());
    String path = file.getPath();
```

2.

```
String path = "./src/androidTest/resources/aa.pdf"
```

But it seems that these two ways are not efficent.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
  String path = "./src/androidTest/resources/aa.pdf"
    File file = new File(path);
```

Get the file path

```
file = new File(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

You can change this line

```
String path = file.getPath();
```

to this

```
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

Also, for a certain parent you can check the path of it like this

```
  String path = "./src/androidTest/resources/aa.pdf" // A valid file path 
    File file = new File(path); 
    String getDirectoryPath = file.getParent(); // Only return path if physical file exist else return null
```

> Edit: in your folder you can right click your pdf file and get the
>   path of it, and you can pass that path inside your String path

Hope it helps

Happy coding !

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but it looks like not work . I use `  Assert.assertTrue(file.exists());`  and `  Assert.assertTrue(file.isFile());` .They all return false.

Comment: where are you using this ? this is another error from what you are asking ?